# Kotlin - How to properly map result using Either?

Tags: android, kotlin, either

I'm trying to read a list of objects from the database and mapping it to another type of list.

```
// Returns either a Failure or the expected result
suspend fun getCountries(): Either<Failure, List<CountryItem>> {
    // Get the result from the database
    val result = countryLocalDataSource.getCountries()

    // Left means Failure
    if (result.isLeft) {
        // Retrieve the error from the database
        lateinit var error: Failure
        result.either({
            error = it
        }, {})

        // Return the result
        return Either.Left(error)
    }

    // The database returns a List of Country objects, we need to map it to another object (CountryItem)
    val countryItems: MutableList<CountryItem> = mutableListOf()

    // Iterate the Country List and construct a new List of CountryItems
    result.map { countries -> {
        countries.forEach {
            // Assign some values from an Enum (localized string resources)
            val countryEnumValue = Countries.fromId(it.id)
            countryEnumValue?.let { countryIt ->
                val countryStringNameRes = countryIt.nameStringRes;

                // Create the new CountryItem object (@StringRes value: Int, isSelected: Bool)
                countryItems.add(CountryItem(countryStringNameRes, false))
            }
        }
    } }

    // Because this is a success, return as Right with the newly created List of CountryItems
    return Either.Right(countryItems)
}
```

For the sake of readability I didn't included the whole `Repository` or the `DAO` classes and I have left comments in the code snippet above.

**In a nutshell**: I'm using Kotlin's [Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html) for accessing the database in a separated thread and I'm handling the response on the `UI Thread`. Using the [Either](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture-Kotlin/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/com/fernandocejas/sample/core/functional/Either.kt) class in order to return two different results (failure or success).

**The above code works, however It's too ugly. Is this the right approach to deliver the result?**

What I'm trying to do is to refactor the code above.

The whole problem is caused by the two different object types. The `Database Data Source API` is returning an `Either<Failure, List<Country>>`, meanwhile the function is expected to return an `Either<Failure, List<CountryItem>>`.

I can't deliver a `List<CountryItem>` directly from the `Database Data Source API`, because Android Studio doesn't let me compile the project (entities implementing interfaces, compile error, etc.). What I'm trying to achieve is to map the `Either` result in a nicer way.

Answer (score 4):

Try using Kotlin's [Result](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/index.html)

So in your case you can write something like:

```
return result.mapCatching { list: List<Country> -> /*return here List<CountryItem>>*/ }
```

And for checking result call:

```
result.fold(
    onSuccess = {...},
    onFailure = {...}
)
```

In order to invoke a constructor you should call `Result.success(T)` or `Result.failure(Throwable)`

Unfortunately, you'll also need to suppress use-as-return-type warnings [How to](http://rustyrazorblade.com/post/2018/2018-12-06-kotlin-result/)

Comment: Why is `Result` superior to `Either`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky `Result` is part of standard library and `Either` is not.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify by checking the type of `Either` and accessing the value directly. In your case:

access `Left` via `result.a` -> `Failure`

access `Right` via `result.b` -> `List<Country>`

ex:

```
when (result) {
    is Either.Left -> {
        val failure: Failure = result.b
        ...
    }
    is Either.Right -> {
        val countries: List<Country> = result.b
        ...
    }
}
```

An alternative is to use the `either()` function (normally this is called `fold()`):

```
result.either(
    { /** called when Left; it == Failure */ }, 
    { /** called when Right; it == List<Country> */ }
)
```

Comment: can you clarify on how to replace either class with fold?

Comment: fold is better than using when-is. If you call `result.asRight()` in the `Either.Left block`, or `result.asLeft()` in the `Either.Right` block, you'll throw an exception. You can avoid that possibility by using fold like: `result.fold({ leftValue -> ... }, { rightValue -> ... })

Answer (score 1):

Assume your `Country` class is defined as follow:

```
data class Country(val name: String) {}
```

and your `CountryItem` class is defined as follow:

```
data class CountryItem(private val name: String, private val population: Int) {}
```

and your `CountryLocalDataSource` class with a method `getCountries()` like this:

```
class DataSource {
    suspend fun getCountries(): Either<Exception, List<Country>> {
        return Either.Right(listOf(Country("USA"), Country("France")))
        //return Either.Left(Exception("Error!!!"))
    }
}
```

then the answer to your question would be:

```
suspend fun getCountryItems(): Either<Exception, List<CountryItem>> {        
    when (val countriesOrFail = DataSource().getCountries()) {
        is Either.Left -> {
            return Either.Left(countriesOrFail.a)
        }
        is Either.Right -> {
            val countryItems = countriesOrFail.b.map {
                CountryItem(it.name, 1000)
            }
            return Either.Right(countryItems)
        }        
    }    
}
```

To call your `getCountryItems()`, here is an example:

```
suspend fun main() {
    when (val countriesOrFail = getCountryItems()) {
        is Either.Left -> {
            println(countriesOrFail.a.message)
        }
        is Either.Right -> {
            println(countriesOrFail.b)       
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the sample code in the playground: https://pl.kotl.in/iiSrkv3QJ

**A note about your map function:**

I'm guessing you don't actually need the result to be a `MutableList<CountryItem>` but you had to define so because you want to add an element as you iterate through the input list `List<Country>`.

Perhaps the following is the case: If you have a `List<Country>` with 2 elements like in the example, and you want to map so that the result becomes a `List<CountryItem>` with also 2 corresponding elements, then you don't need to call forEach inside a `fun` that gets passed to the higher-order function `map`. But this may be an entirely new question.